# Selected value get from DB into dropdown select box

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have an Employee Form Edit.
My problem is, my function for the edit is working fine but I can't get the value of my employee type.

I have 4 employee type:

- Staff
- Supervisor
- Manager
- Super User

Every time I go to edit form, the employee type on drop down is always on staff (I want to display, if the employee is "Manager" then the drop box show Manager).

This is the code for **editroledetails.blade.php**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="editCustomerType">Customer Type</label><br/>
    <select name="editCustomerType">
        <option value="Staff">Staff</option>
        <option value="Supervisor">Supervisor</option>
        <option value="Manager">Manager</option>
        <option value="Super User">Super User</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**Controller function**

```
public function editroledetails(Request $request)
{
    $user = \Auth::user();
    $userphone = 0;
    $reportTo = DB::select(DB::raw("select username from customer_type where customer_type = 'Supervisor' or customer_type ='Manager' "));

    $select = DB::select(DB::raw("select customer_type from customer_type "));
    $data = [
        'editUsername' => $request->editUsername,
        'editNik' => $request->editNik,
        'editEmail' => $request->editEmail,
        'editRegIdentities' => $request->editRegIdentities,
        'editReportTo' => $request->editReportTo,
        'editID' => $request->editID
    ];
    return view('editroledetails', compact('user', 'userphone', 'data', 'reportTo', 'select'));
}
```

Comment: So where in your code are you reading what role the employee currently has …?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label for="editCustomerType">Customer Type</label><br/>
     <select name="editCustomerType">
           @if($user->customer_type == 'Staff')
              <option value="Staff">Staff</option>
           @endif
           @if($user->customer_type == 'Supervisor')
               <option value="Supervisor">Supervisor</option>
           @endif
           @if($user->customer_type == 'Manager')
               <option value="Manager">Manager</option>
            @endif
            @if($user->customer_type == 'Super User')
               <option value="Super User">Super User</option>
            @endif
     </select>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `selected` attribute on the select options

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="editCustomerType">Customer Type</label><br/>
    <select name="editCustomerType">
        <option value="Staff" @if($user->customer_type == 'Staff')selected@endIf>Staff</option>
        <option value="Supervisor" @if($user->customer_type == 'Supervisor')selected@endIf>Supervisor</option>
        <option value="Manager" @if($user->customer_type == 'Manager')selected@endIf>Manager</option>
        <option value="Super User" @if($user->customer_type == 'Super User')selected@endIf>Super User</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to show the selected item in select list

```
<?php
    $customerTypes = [
        'Staff' => 'Staff',
        'Supervisor' => 'Supervisor',
        'Manager' => 'Manager',
        'Super User' => 'Super User',
    ];
?>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="editCustomerType">Customer Type</label><br/>
    <select name="editCustomerType">
        @foreach($customerTypes as $type)
            <?php
                $selected = "";
                @if($user->customer_type == $type) {
                    $selected = "selected";
                }
            ?>
            <option value="{{ $type }}" {{ $selected }} >{{ $type }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
```